# Modify Excel VBA code to make it work faster

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file with more then 100k rows, but the structure is simple:

```
Date       | Name-Position-Color | Summ
17.11.2015 |"Name1               | 8813,52
           | Position1           |
          _|_Color1"            _|_
19.08.2015 |"Name2               | 3587,86
           | Position3           |
          _|_Color5"            _|_
12.01.2015 |"Name3               | 14,63
           | Position16          |
          _|_Color7"            _|_
07.12.2015 |"Name4               | 7129,97
           | Position11          |
           | Color3"             |
```

Result should be twelve identically formed tables from "Jan" to "Dec" sliced from "Name-Position-Color" column sheet1 placed into sheet3 as "Name-slice" -column and "Position-slice" -head row. The "color" part is no longer needed. Tables should be filled with multiplied "Name-slice" by "Position-slice" including a period in which they're positioned in the first list. I hope this is informative enough to understand. So, I've managed to write a macro (it's located just a few lines below), but it works really slow even when I have only 228 rows in the list. It had worked fast just before I've added a calculation part. I think object programming could save some time, but I haven't learned it yet. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me the way to improve my code, so it'll work faster. Any advice would be really helpful too... Thanks. You can see the whole code below.

```
Sub tablesByMonths()

'def column in sheet1
colNum1 = 2
'def column in sheet3
colNum3 = 2 '2 is minimal for correct macro work
'def last row in sheet1
lastRow1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, colNum1).End(xlUp).Row
'def first row in sheet1
firstRow1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,     colNum1).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'def last row in sheet3
step = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False                  'turns off dynamic screen update
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual       'turns off automatic formulas

'clears all used range in a sheet3
Worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Clear

'this counts months from Jan to Dec
For per = 1 To 12

'def last row in sheet3
lastRow3_1 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, colNum3).End(xlUp).Row
'puts current number from per loop and adds "/01/2015"
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow3_1 + step, colNum3 - 1).Value = per & "/01/2015"
'converts date into month format
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow3_1 + step, colNum3 - 1).NumberFormat = "mmmm"

'loop through the entire list in a sheet1 column colNum1
For x = firstRow1 To lastRow1

    'def current cell value
    curVal1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, colNum1)
    'def first space position in curVal1
    spacePos1 = InStr(1, curVal1, Chr(10), vbBinaryCompare)
    'def second space position in curVal1
    spacePos2 = InStr(spacePos1 + 1, curVal1, Chr(10), vbBinaryCompare)
    'def first word in curVal1 cell and place it into sheet3
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow3_1 + step - 1 + x, colNum3) = Mid(curVal1, 1, spacePos1 - 1)
    'def second word in curVal1 cell and place it into sheet3
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow3_1 + step - 2 + x, colNum3 + 1) = Mid(curVal1, spacePos1 + 1, spacePos2 - spacePos1 - 1)

Next x

'def last row in a new list sheet3
lastRow3 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, colNum3).End(xlUp).Row
'def last row in a new list sheet3
firstRow3 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, colNum3).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row

'del replicas from list with names and sort in ascend order in sheet3
With Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(firstRow3, colNum3), Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow3, colNum3))

    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    .Sort key1:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(firstRow3, colNum3), Header:=xlNo

End With

'del replicas from list with positions and sort in ascend order in sheet3
With Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(firstRow3 - 1, colNum3 + 1), Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow3, colNum3 + 1))

    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    .Sort key1:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(firstRow3 - 1, colNum3 + 1), Header:=xlNo

End With

'def new last cell for list of positions in sheet3
lastRow3_2 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, colNum3 + 1).End(xlUp).Row

'transpose sorted list of items into head row
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(firstRow3 - 1, colNum3 + 1), Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(firstRow3 - 1, lastRow3_2 - firstRow3 + colNum3 + 1)) = Worksheets("Sheet3").Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(firstRow3 - 1, colNum3 + 1), Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow3_2, colNum3 + 1)))
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(firstRow3, colNum3 + 1), Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastRow3_2, colNum3 + 1)).Clear

'def last row in a new list sheet3 after deleting dublicates (need a method of calling a function to do it repeatedly)
lastRow3n = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, colNum3).End(xlUp).Row
'loop through list of names
For namesList = firstRow3 To lastRow3n

    For headRow = colNum3 + 1 To lastRow3_2 - firstRow3 + colNum3 + 1

        'takes position name of the current position in the head row list
        currentValue = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(namesList, colNum3) & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(firstRow3 - 1, headRow) & Chr(42)
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(namesList, headRow).Value = "0.00"                'def starting value
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(namesList, headRow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"     'establishes cell format
        'loop through list in the base table
        For firstList = firstRow1 To lastRow1

            listValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(firstList, colNum1).Value
            'checks if value in the first list equal to the current combined value
            If listValue Like currentValue Then

                Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(namesList, headRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(namesList, headRow).Value + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(firstList, colNum1 + 1).Value

            End If

        Next firstList

    Next headRow

Next namesList

Next per

Application.ScreenUpdating = True                   'turns on dynamic screen update
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic    'turns on automatic formulas

End Sub
```

Comment: This question is better suited for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and might even be off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I **definitely** recommend [codereview.se]. Whilst specific speed optimisations **can** be On-Topic for Stack Overflow, in this case what you **really** need is not a speed tune-up, but a thorough guide to VBA best practices.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that source.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small idea - in order to understand where your code takes most of its time, write the code below in 4-5 places. 
Then you would see the place where you should improve. 
Then share again, just that place, or probably you can improve yourself :)

```
Debug.Print "TEST1 " & Now
Debug.Print "TEST2 " & Now
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely try this method.